# ADK Auto connect without confirmation

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I am working on android application which connects android device via USB to mega adk 2560 board. When I connect my android device to adk board and open my application it asks me to choose adk mode in dialog box. I don't want that dialog instead I want that it should auto connect to the board.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you will be able to ignore this dialog with normal devices

> Its android devices policies to notify user when some external USB
>   connected .

It may  required to embed new device which programmed   like to not show that kind of notification  and its normally unusual